# Laptop crashed after plugging dual monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

My laptop is several years old. Tonight I thought it would be a great idea to plug in a second monitor (vga) plus a TV (hdmi). The TV worked, it displayed my desktop fine. The monitor didn’t work so I went in the settings in my computer and only had time to play with « identify » and « detect » for a few minutes before it crashed. Loud noise and weird freezy screens.. I held the power button on my laptop to shut it off. Now the laptop seems to boot but screen stays black. Did I mess up my video card or something? Not too tech savvy here (clearly).

Comment: "Loud noise" sounds like maybe an old capacitor popped.  If it's still under warranty, just take it to the shop.  Otherwise, if you are savvy enough to open the case and look around, you are likely to spot it if that's what happened.  If you spot an obvious problem like that, what to do next will be pretty focused.

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful connecting a monitor did any physical harm (e.g. popped capacitor), unless there were serious issues with power supplies in both monitor and PC. More likely, a significant video setting was changed.

More information is needed, e.g. operating system (Windows 10? Ubuntu? something else?), what made the noise (PC? monitor? external speakers?).

If Windows, you might try [Safe Boot](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10). If that doesn't work, create (or have a friend make) a "[rescue disk](https://lifehacker.com/5984707/five-best-system-rescue-discs)" or "live boot" media, such as [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). These have their own video drivers, or can find the correct video driver on the web. If you can boot from the disk or USB drive and your system behaves normally, then you know that no serious damage occurred.

If the hardware is not broken, it may be easiest to reinstall the old OS, or to install one permanently, once it is found to work from live media.